# Is there a definitive guide to tabindex behavior in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, focus, tabindex

I maintain an application framework based on Windows Forms. I don't have the luxury of specifying tab order explicitly - controls are added at runtime, so Visual Studio doesn't help.

Tab order, especially when containers are involved, is something of a mystery. Does a resource exist that describes how, at runtime, Windows Forms manages tabbing order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posted answers are not correct, Z-order has nothing to do with tab order.  It is just a coincidence that the order in which you drop controls on a form also sets the z-order and the TabIndex property value in a predictable way.  It gets out of whack as soon as you use the Format menu to move controls to the front or back.  Only TabIndex matters.  Intuitively: there wouldn't be a need for the property otherwise.

No shortcuts here, if you can't use the designer to set the TabIndex property for you then you have to set it yourself.  You have to write the code.  It isn't typically that difficult, just assign it sequentially from the last used value, add the controls in tabbing order.  Leave a gap in assigned TabIndex values if you need to insert them between controls that you added with the designer.

Comment: How do containers such as groupbox or panel interact with tabbing order? Should I set tabindex on them as well? Or does tabbing (within a form) proceed sequentially from lowest to highest ?  THanks for you answer so far!

Comment: The container has a TabIndex just like any other control.  Once it gains the focus, tabbing goes between controls inside the container.  Until the last one is reached, the next Tab press goes back to the parent.  Note that TabIndex numbering of these controls starts back at 0.  Check out the arguments for the Control.SelectNextControl() method for insight.  They are typically all set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that MSDN has the [definitive guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx).

Also important: [`UpdateZOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.updatezorder.aspx), as pointed out in the comments by [@jswolf19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292067/jswolf19).

Comment: That's hardly a definitive guide. (MSDN might have such a thing, but that scant doc with no extra discussion isn't it.)

Answer (score 0):

Tab index is set as the order in which things are created. But you can specify tab index at runtime anyway so you shouldn't have any problems in getting the behaviour you want.